# PhoneGap: different behavior Simulator vs. Device

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova

Very strange problem:
I've created a small HTML5 canvas game with box2dweb.js.
So far, all my work has been on desktop and today I've decided to move it to the iPhone (which usually consists of wrapping the app in a PhoneGap/Cordova application, change a few settings, and that's it.

The problem is, when I run the app on my desktop browsers (Chrome, Safari) as well as the iPhone and iPad simulators - everything works correctly - but when I actually deploy to my device (iPhone 4S) only **some** of the pictures show up. In fact, only the player sprite animation plays, and everything else (while still there physically) does not get drawn unless it doesn't have a specific  animation (whether it's a sequence of images or just one image).

What seems even more strange, is that only the player entity is being drawn (with animation, too!) but all other entities that have animations are simply not drawn.

I've attached images to show the differences:

[image: Everything gets drawn on iOS simulator and desktop]
[image: Only the player gets drawn on the actual device]

My question is - where do I even start debugging this? I tried running the index.html page without the cordova app on the iOS simulator so I could access the debug console, but there were no issues. How is this even possible? I was under the impression that if it worked as a web page, it should work as a PhoneGap app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've solved the problem. It was incredibly simple but hard to find. It's not even a PhoneGap problem:

The game has a level editor, and so it also has a saving/loading mechanism. While I specify all the images as './graphics/image.png', when a level gets deserialized it saves the loaded image's source, and not the original './graphics...' path. So the problem was that I was trying to load local files from my computer to my iPhone. I guess it was a path problem after all...